# Remove text after character only on lines that contains specific string Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a Json file that contains a "tag" attribute with multiple tags, I want to keep only the first tag.

Example:

> "tags": "tag1, tag2, etc",

Desired Output:

> "tags": "tag1",

With the following expression, I can remove everything after the first `,` and replace it with `",`, but this will affect everything from my file, and I need only the lines with "tags"

```
\,.*$
```

I have also tried to bookmark these lines and work only on them, but I don't think is possible

Comment: You **can't** parse JSON with regex, use a JSON parser.

Comment: @Toto I don't need to parse anything, I just need to replace some text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the data is exactly as in the example, this will do the job:

Find what : `("tags": ")([^,]*)\,.*`
Replace with: `\1\2",`

Explanation follows.

Search string:

`("tags": ")` : Represents the text `"tags": "`, enclosed within the first
group.
It is a bit redundant, but I worded it this way for you to be able
to replace it with anything you like, including another regex sub-expression.

`([^,]*)` : Represents any number of characters that are not a comma,
enclosed within the second group.

`\,.*` : Represents comma followed by any number of characters until the
end of the line. Not enclosed within a group since it is to be discarded.

Replacement string:

`\1` : The first matched group
`\2` : The second matched group
`",` : The characters `",`

Comment: Explanation added.